# Filter by date range when the date is split into multiple fields

Tags: sql, db2

I am working with a database that stores dates in multiple fields as integers (mock field names):

- Century: CC01: 20
- Year: YR01: 13
- Month: MO01: 7
- Day: DY01: 22

I can formulate a date as so: `DATE((CC01 * 100 + YR01) || '-' || MO01 || '-' || DY01)`

The problem is when I need to filter over a range of dates. For example, if I want to select the past 90 days, I could write something like this...

`WHERE DATE((CC01 * 100 + YR01) || '-' || MO01 || '-' || DY01) >= CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS`

The problem here is performance. I am searching for an efficient way of writing this formula that keeps functions limited to the right-hand side of the equation.

Here is an example that would work with today's date (I don't need to worry about century, and I am leaving out some detail):

`WHERE CC01 = 20 AND YR01 >= RIGHT(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS),2) AND MO01 >= MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS) AND DY01 >= DAY(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)`

This only works because going back 7 days keeps us in the current month and year. I would also prefer not to have a huge set of ANDs and ORs (if possible).

Comment: Selecting it as an extra column, so you only have to define it once? And use that column in your where clause. And maybe it's easier converting the date to a UNIX timestamp (integer), and limiting that `BETWEEN val1 AND val2`

Comment: The issue I have is that the table is several hundred million records. Any functions on the table values will take forever to process and use too much temp space.

Comment: You could create a DB2 view that converts the multiple date integers into a DB2 date.  You already provided the formula.

Comment: I only have read permissions to this data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have found a solution.

```
        CC01 = 20
        AND
        YR01 >= RIGHT(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS),2)
        AND NOT
            (
            YR01 = RIGHT(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS),2)
            AND
            MO01 = MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS)
            AND
            DY01 < DAY(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS)
            )
        AND NOT
            (
            YR01 = RIGHT(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS),2)
            AND
            MO01 < MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 220 DAYS)
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to modify the DB schema?
If so you could consider a 'generated column' for the date :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/expression_generated_columns?lang=en

Comment: Unfortunately no, the access is read only. Any solution will have to take place in the WHERE statement as I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a limit to the length of the date ranges you will query?
For short ranges, you could generate a verbose dynamic SQL like :

```
WHERE
    (CC01 = 20 AND YR01 = 07 AND MO01 = 02 AND DY01 = 01)
 OR (CC01 = 20 AND YR01 = 07 AND MO01 = 03 AND DY01 = 04)
 OR (CC01 = 20 AND YR01 = 07 AND MO01 = 04 AND DY01 = 03)
```

You'd have to profile to see whether the longer query compensates for the faster lookup (my intuition says function calls across hundreds of millions of records will be slower, although intuition is never to be trusted).

Comment: Unfortunately, the date ranges need to be dynamic

Comment: if your date range is limited to a few hundred, whereas your DB table is a few hundred million - then it is definitely better to do extra processing per-requested-date rather than per-DB-row.

Comment: yes, I meant to generate the SQL query in whatever code is calling in to the database

Comment: or add a stored procedure that takes two dates and generates a SQL string, if it all needs to happen inside the DB

Comment: a stored procedure like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181598/dynamic-month-year-columns-per-date-range except inside the while loop you would add a new OR... clause to a string

Comment: An additional concern with this method is that I am running an openquery though MS SQL 2012 and have a text limit.

Comment: if the SQL generation happens inside a stored procedure, I don't think the text limit would be a problem.  The query that you would run as a user would be "exec myProcedure(date1, date2)".  It would only be inside the procedure that a large SQL query string would be generated and executed - so I don't think the text limit would affect it.

Comment: The only sproc I can create is on the MS SQL server, not the DB2. I only have read permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to convert to a date

```
CREATE FUNCTION parts2date (cc int, yy int, mm int,  dd int ) returns date
    LANGUAGE SQL
    CONTAINS SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    RETURN DATE( RIGHT(DIGITS(cc),2)||RIGHT(DIGITS(yy),w)||'-'
               ||RIGHT(DIGITS(mm),2)||'-'||RIGHT(DIGITS(dd),2) );
  END;
```

You might add a condition handler, to return null on an error.

Comment: I only have read permissions to the DB. I cannot create a function. Also, this function would need to run on every row before a range in the where would work. This would cause performance issues.

Comment: Conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated before almost everything else.  Perhaps DB2 works differently on your platform, but on IBM i the performance would be better, not worse.

Comment: Your DBA, or equivalent person, may be willing to create an applicable function for you.  Generally we like to do things that improve performance.  ;-)